# Python3 vs Python 3.8

Tags: python, python3, python-2.7

Ubuntu (older than 20.04 LTS) ships with Python 3 and python 2 both. When `python` was typed in terminal, python2.7 opens and to open python 3.6, `python3` command is needed. However `python3.6` also works.

So my doubt is why `python3` and `python3.6` both work? Technically since I have python3.6 installed, only `python3.6` should work. But then why `python3` works as well?

**EDIT 1**

When I type `python` and press tabs twice (which shows possible commands), I see python3 and python3.8 both.

My doubt is what is the difference between the `python3` command and `python3.6` command in their execution.

Comment: it is still installed though after upgrade

Comment: @user535733 how is this relevant to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python3` command is a link to whatever version of Py3 the system is currently using.

This is very handy so scripts don't need to keep track of the exact version installed and don't break at the next release-upgrade.

Comment: Where can I check other links which other apps have?

Comment: @AbhayPatil your question is vague. It's not clear what you are asking. Can you provide a non-Python3 example?

Comment: Just like python, do other apps also use such links?

Comment: Sure - look through /bin, /sbin. and the other directories in your $PATH. Example: `ls -l /usr/bin` and you will see a few